# C++: setting DebugInformationFormat using Clang and VS14

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, clang

I'm trying to build a simple hello-world program using `cmake`, `clang` and `VS14` with `Clang 3.7`.

```
cmake ../src -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -T "v140_clang_3_7"
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (test)
add_executable(test testfile.cpp)
```

I get the error that DebugInformationFormat has an incorrect value:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Clang
.targets(206,5): error : Element <DebugInformationFormat> has an value of
"ProgramDatabase". [...\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c45da.vcxproj]
```

I did some research and tried to override the default value in my `CMakeLists.txt` without success

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g2 -gdwarf-2")
```

Whatever I tried so far, didn't work out (of course I cleaned the build directory before every new cmake)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem on build project with CMake, VS15, Clang 3.7.

I just got an LLVM snapshotbuild for windows form http://llvm.org/builds/
Install a recent version of clang (at the time of writing v3.9.0).

After the installation Properties -> General -> Platform Tools -> LLVM-vs2014 (Switch to LLVM-vs2014), and build.